# IP-configuration with 0.0.0.0 - Meaning?

Tags: networking, apache2, webserver, ip

**What's the meaning of 0.0.0.0 in an IP-configuration?**

For example in Apache "httpd.conf": `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/) or [here](https://superuser.com/questions/949428/).

Comment: @kortewegdevries Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@st88

In the context of routing tables, a network destination of 0.0.0.0 is used with a network mask of 0 to depict the default route as a destination subnet. This destination is expressed as "0.0.0.0/0" in CIDR notation. It matches all addresses in the IPv4 address space and is present on most hosts, directed towards a local router.

In routing tables, 0.0.0.0 can also appear in the gateway column. This indicates that the gateway to reach the corresponding destination subnet is unspecified. This generally means that no intermediate routing hops are necessary because the system is directly connected to the destination.

for more information you can view https://www.howtogeek.com/225487/what-is-the-difference-between-127.0.0.1-and-0.0.0.0/.

the information are from Wikipedia.. hope that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It means that your Apache server listens on all available IPs of the machine (on port 80).

For example, assuming you have two ethernet interfaces (`eth0` and `eth1`) with respectively assigned IPs `192.168.0.2/24` and `172.17.0.2/24`, your server will be reachable at:

- 192.168.0.2:80
- 172.17.0.2:80
- 127.0.0.1:80 (which is tipically the address of the loopback interface)